# 3-Way Switch with Dimmer - Humming?

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

We recently upgraded our dining room light fixture, which now has 8 light bulb sockets. In turn, the wife wanted to add a dimmer to the circuit to control the lighting. The light is control by a 3-way circuit; one switch is stand alone on one wall and the other switch is in a box with another switch that controls the kitchen lighting in the other room.

Yesterday, I removed the existing 3-way standalone switch and replaced it with a Lutron Diva dimmer switch for 3-way circuit. I replaced the current bulbs with 60W ecosmart dimmable bulbs. The switches worked correctly; however, when the light was on you could noticeably hear humming coming from the existing switch for the 3-way.

My next step was to move the dimmer switch instead to the other location next to the kitchen light switch to see if that did anything for the humming. I reinstalled the existing 3-way paddle switch in the single location and then installed the dimmer at the two switch location. Wiring looked standard and easy to wire up. Turned out breaker to have it pop and burn up the dimmer switch completely. My only thought at that point was did I have the travelers on opposite locations between the two switches? It didn't make sense that it would pop though. I removed the dimmer, obviously, and reinstalled the existing switch back. Everything worked again like it was supposed to and you did not hear any buzzing coming from the switches. I am a bit puzzled as I installed the same dimmer for the stairwell light and I don't get any buzzing from the existing switches or dimmer.

I went back today and bought a new dimmer switch and 40W bulbs this time to see if that would make any difference. Any feedback from anyone on this?

Comment: Sometimes dimmers buzz...  Make sure the dimmer specifically says it's compatible with LED bulbs, and make sure the bulbs are compatible.  Sometimes more expensive bulbs will have less of a chance of creating a buzz, but it's really hard to tell without just trying.

Comment: That's the thing, the dimmer switch itself isn't buzzing. When the dimmer switch was put onto the circuit, the existing paddle switch was the one starting to buzz.

Comment: I did go with Phillips LED dimming bulbs this time to see if it helps. Lutron Diva is also compatible with LED bulbs.

Comment: A dimmer switch works by chopping up the normal smooth sine wave of electricity into little pulses.  The pulsing electricity is what causes the buzz, and it can be in the filament of a bulb or in any other component.  Maybe also try to replace the standard switch.  The contacts could be worn or loose.  It sounds like you've checked everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was a bit puzzled myself, but I may also switch that standard switch as well. I just couldn't imagine that 60W would be the cause, but going to try the rest of the ideas I have to see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: Is the older 3-way switch, the one now buzzing, a plain switch or something special?

Comment: Plain Legrand 3-way paddle switch. Nothing special. House was built in 2015 so it is just the builder standard ones I am sure.

Comment: Update for group; I installed new Lutron dimmer at single switch location, installed the Philips 40W LED dimmable bulbs and switch the existing 3-way switch on the other side to another of the same kind to try and rule out if that was going bad. 3-way switches and dimmer work as designed; however, there is still a small hum coming from the existing switch location. Not as pronounced as previously but it is still there.

Comment: Are the paddle switch and the dimmer switch on the same circuit? Which box does power come in at?

Comment: They are on the same circuit and I am 99% sure the power comes in at the switch double switch location where the buzzing is coming from.